# longest sub-sequence in both directions

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, strings, subsequences

Given a character array A of size n, compute the length of a longest sub-sequence S of A such that, S read backward is also a sub-sequence of A.

Example: A = cabca

the sub-sequence S = abc is the longest of such sub-sequences.

reading S forward (abc): c**abc**a

reading S reverse (cba): **c**a**b**c**a**

How to compute the length of such an S ?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to reduce your problem to *Longest Common Subsequence*. I'll let you figure out how.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you give a bigger hint please ?

Comment: Unfortunately it would be difficult for me to give further hints without giving away the solution.

Comment: I call it longest 2 sided sub-sequence, the following is my recurrence.

                  | 0 if i>j
l2sss(i,j) = | 1 if i = j
                  | 2 + l2sss(i+1, j-1) if s[i]==s[j] //include both
                  | max (2 + l2sss(i+1, find_last_of(s[i])-1), l2sss(i+1, j)

two cases within max 1> include s[i], so the problem size become i+1 (because s[i] was included) to find_last_of(s[i]-1) and 2> I exclude s[i]. This does not seem to work (when I implemented this, it does not evaluate to the right answer) and seems to force the string S to be a palindrome (it wasn't a requirement).

Comment: Sorry, I tried to pretty print that recurrence equation, it did not work out as I expected.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is wrong with my recurrence ?

Comment: You don't need me to debug your recurrence. Just take an example in which it doesn't work, and see what goes wrong.